# What is the equivalent of an empty object in immutable.js?

Tags: immutable.js

In immutable.js what is the equivalent of an empty object?

My code is:

```
let iState = fromJS(state)
iState = iState.setIn(['ui', 'drafts'], {})
return iState.toJS()
```

But I think I should not use `{}` when using `setIn`. Please advise what I should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best 'empty' data structure to use will depend on your use case (and I highly recommend looking at the other data structures and use their advantages) but for the most common interface/expected behavior and structure - [Record](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record) will be the closest analog. That said, I also recommend looking into the [Map](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) data structure as it has a bit more functionality baked in than Record that you may find you need.

Comment: iState = iState.setIn(['ui', 'drafts'], Map()) works great thx